# How to tell when oAuth access token for Office 365 is no longer valid

Tags: validation, oauth, oauth-2.0, office365

I have an app that incorporates social login with Office 365. The user is authenticated against an organization's tenant and then has a user created on my end with the Office 365 `access_token` associated with that user.

However, if that user is for some reason no longer valid (they get fired, they quit, etc), I no longer want that user to have access to my app.

What is the best way to ensure that an Office 365 `access_token` is still valid? Is there a webhook for when a user is removed or had their permissions changed? Or is there an endpoint I can hit to just simply validate an `access_token`?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer for this?